# Connecting a second display, and display problems with the 1st display

Tags: display

I have a Toshiba Satellite L55W-C5320, That I run both windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.10 on.
It has an I7 processor and an integrated "HD" Intel graphics card, that supports running up to 2 screens at a time.

I like working with multiple monitors, and usually have a 16" Dell LCD screen as a secondary screen.

I have no problems with this setup while running windows.

But occasionally while running Ubuntu (often after switching from windows to Ubuntu, or after restarting Ubuntu). Ubuntu decides to freak out and I start seeing purple lines on the bottom 1/3 of my laptops screen. And the top 1/3 of the screen darkens. This error doesn't always occur, and seems to disappear and reappear at random.

**My question is:**

What steps should I take in order to find the cause of this error? And how can I go about fixing this display bug?

**Things I have tried so far:**

1. Changing the refresh rate of my laptops primary display.
2. Changing the resolution to less then the natural resolution of my laptops
   primary display.
3. Changing both the refresh rate of my laptops primary display, and the resolution
4. Restarting Ubuntu (Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't)
5. Restarting without having the secondary display plugged in, vs restarting with the secondary display plugged in.
6. Unplugging the secondary display (This sometimes causes the problematic purple lines to disappear, but not always).